# Asp.net mcv 4 web application host in iis 7 on windwos 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-7, iis-7

I'm new in asp.net world.  I made it by visual studio project template c#->web->visual studio 2013-> ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application. I managed to make my website and launch it from visual studio 2013. My development directory content:-

App_Data (directory)

App_Start (directory)

bin (directory)

Content (directory)

Controllers (directory)

Filters (directory)

Models (directory)

obj (directory)

Properties (directory)

Scripts (directory)

Views (directory)

AspInfoTaulu.csproj

AspInfoTaulu.csproj.user

favicon.ico

Global.asax

Global.asax.cs

packages.config

Web.config

Web.Debug.config

Web.Release.config

I publish the website from visual studio publish. Publish directory contains:-

bin (directory)

Content (directory)

Scripts (directory)

Views (directory)

favicon.ico

Global.asax

packages.config

Web.config

I made a directory at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webdir and copy the contain's of publish directory. Add new website in iis manager. By following several instructions. Could not managed to host it in iis. I got various error. Could someone inform me how to host asp.net mvc 4 website in iis 7? Error screenshot:-

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the route look like? Is it the default route?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that your Global.asax (existing in application root) is correctly located via the physical path:

1. open your iis-manager
2. Expand sites on the right pane
3. right click on your site
4. choose 'manage website' > 'advanced settings'
5. on attribute 'phyical path' choose the destination of the Global.asax located in your application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open c:/ drive.
2. In this drive open **inetpub** folder.
3. In this inetpub open **wwwroot** folder.
4. Copy that folder, which is store your publish application.
    **eg.**I publish my application in **d:/myapp** folder, so copy that folder.
5. Copy myapp folder and paste into **wwwroot** folder.
6. When you past folder in wwwroot folder then open one dialog box, in this dialog box you click on **continue** button.
7. Open **IIS manager**.
8. Expand **Sites** menu.
9. In this sites menu expand **Default Web Site**.
   10.Right click on your **hosting application**(your application) name.
   11.Expand **Manage Application*8 menu then click to **browse***.